# AWS AppSync: Add multiple query string items in request mapping template not work

Tags: aws-appsync

I have a request mapping template as follow: This is mapped to a GraphQL query called getPost

```
{
  "version": "2018-05-29",
  "method": "GET",
  ## E.G. if full path is https://api.xxxxxxxxx.com/posts then resourcePath would be /posts **
  "resourcePath": "/event1/wp-json/wp/v2/posts",
  "params":{
      ## "query":$util.toJson($ctx.args),
      "query":{
        "slug": "$ctx.args.slug",
        "lang": "$ctx.args.lang"
      },
      "headers": {
          "Authorization": "$ctx.request.headers.Authorization"
      }
  }
}
```

A valid JSON response URL is this:

```
http://my_domain/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?slug=new-post-en&lang=zh-hant
```

But when I tested in "Queries" using this:

```
query MyQuery {
  getPost(slug: "new-post-en", lang: "zh-hant") {
    id
  }
}
```

No result return, but it should have at least one record returned.

Can you please tell me what's wrong with my request?

Thank you.

**UPDATED** Add Schema:

```
type Post {
    id: ID!
    date: String!
    slug: String!
    type: String!
    link: AWSURL
    title: AWSJSON!
    content: AWSJSON!
    excerpt: AWSJSON!
}

type Query {
    getPost(slug: String!, lang: String): Post
    getPosts: [Post]
}

schema {
    query: Query
}
```

Comment: can you add your schema to the question. Only the Query section along with the type definition of the types used in Query.

Comment: @GSSwain It is added.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

- When we make a request to `http://my_domain/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?slug=new-post-en&lang=zh-hant`, it will return an array in terms of JSON
- However, in the schema, the query is: `getPost(slug: String!, lang: String): Post`
- Notice the return type `Post`, it is not an array
- So to get a valid return, we change it from

  - `getPost(slug: String!, lang: String): Post` to
  - `getPost(slug: String!, lang: String): [Post]`

And hola~ It works!